# How to add routerLink on ternary operator?

Tags: angular, onclick, href, router

In my angular HTML code there is ternary condition shown below

```
<my-tag [top-position]="find.distance ? find.distance.code : find.volume.code" [rClass]="r.rClass"></my-tag>
```

I am trying to make the above content clickable, so that when user clicks they are redirected to different route. I have difficulty integrating routerLink to the above code

Comment: [routerLink]="condition ? ['/my-path'] : null"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've to route by school type!

In .ts file

```
edType: string;
ngOnInit(){ this.edType == 'M' }
```

In HTML

```
<ion-item button detail [routerLink]="[edType == 'M' ? 'middle-school' : 'high-school']">
   <ion-icon name="log-in-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label> Switch School </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```